# How to get the jquery effect with siblings alternative method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a contact form, but not expert in jquery. The below code work in the HTML file. I am developing this form with a WordPress plugin. When I have configured below the Html form, the div style structure got to look indifferent and not working the jquery effect.

the effect work on this **form**:

```
<div class="tm-form-field tm-form-fieldhalf">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required="required">
    <span class="tm-form-animatedline"></span>
</div>

<div class="tm-form-field tm-form-fieldhalf">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required="required">
    <span class="tm-form-animatedline"></span>
</div>
```

But not work on this **configured form**:

```
<div class="tm-form-field tm-form-fieldhalf">
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Full Name"></span><br>
    <span class="tm-form-animatedline"></span>
 </div>

<div class="tm-form-field tm-form-fieldhalf">
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Email Address"></span>
    <p></p>
    <p><span class="tm-form-animatedline"></span></p>
</div>
```

How can i get working on configured form, the jquery effect code is below:

```
/* Contact Form Effect */
        contactFormEffect: function () {
            $('.tm-form-field').on('focus', 'input, textarea', function () {
                $(this).siblings('.tm-form-animatedline').css('width', '100%');
            });
            $('.tm-form-field').on('focusout', 'input, textarea', function () {
                $(this).siblings('.tm-form-animatedline').css('width', 0);
                var $this = $(this);
                if ($this.val().trim().length !== 0) {
                    $(this).siblings('.tm-form-animatedline').css('width', '100%');
                }
            });
        },
```

Comment: You've changed the relationship of the elements. The `input` is no longer at the same level as the `span` with the "tm-form-animatedline" class.

Comment: yes, is there way to get the css class for getting the effect

Comment: Think of it logically. Your event target is now one level deeper than it was previously. So your sibling is now your niece/nephew. How do you navigate to that person? I'd probably go to the sibling, then down to the child.

Comment: yes, i have tried with children, but not getting the result

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to share what you've tried? It is part of [ask]...

Comment: I have tried with jQuery children() Method, thanks